# I am having a problem in pandas python which i think might be due to wrong use of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have my dataset looking like this:

```
 A    B    C    CompanyName   Sector    year
 4    9    3         d          10       2000 
 2    4    45        f          78       2001
 7   53    55        y          99       2000
```

I want to have it looking like this

```
 MeanA MeanB MeanC medianC   Sector  Year
 bla     bla   bla  bla        bla    bla
 bla     bla   bla  bla        bla    bla
 bla     bla   bla  bla        bla    bla
 bla     bla   bla  bla        bla    bla
```

So the first thing that came on my mind is to group by sector and year then use .agg() to calculate meanC medianC meanb meanA. But the problem is for meanC i noticed strange empty cells even though medianC exists so at least it should assume that value.

this is an example of code:

```
 Data=Data.groupby(['Sector','year']).agg({'A':'mean', 'B':'mean', "C":['mean', 'median']})
```

I think I am using the groupby function in a wrong way, any help will be appreciated

PS. my dataset contains about 120k rows going from 2000 to 2015 with multiple companies

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show the code?

Comment: I just updated the post

Comment: How many different groups do you have? `df[['Sector', 'year']].value_counts().size`?

Comment: @Corralien 995 which is the number i would expect

Comment: @KingOtto theoretically yes but in reality no. I mean I agree with you that is should work perfectly. But looking at my data C column values are present on a company level so when I aggregate on a sector level i would expect values to be there, but instead i have NaN in some sectors in some years

Comment: It does work.. I cannot post a screenshot in a comment, but I would. ;) The problem is in your 120k data rows somewhere, not in your command per se. let's find the specific 'weird rows' that cause the 'strange mean value'

Comment: What do you mean by weird rows? Having all the column as float where i do calculations what should I expect?

Comment: Is `pd.to_numeric(df['C'])` raised an error?

Comment: I prefer not to guess. :) Your small example works, your code  is ok. You mention "i noticed strange empty cells" - sounds like not all mean values are corrupt, but only those relate to specific "season-year" combinations. i would start by investigating those

Comment: @Corralien no its returning this:                       
 

19       0.999874
196      0.694758
318      0.996133
369      0.977541
402      1.000518
           ...   
10432    0.999998
10452    1.022098
10813    0.999973
11310    0.999920
11419    0.999389
Name: financialDependenceAverage, Length: 119773, dtype: float64

Comment: If this was not raised an error, it means all values in `C` column are numeric (or nan) so you should not get empty cells.

Comment: I think you are getting empty cells because you have NA values in your original data.
try: Data.fillna(0).groupby(['Sector','year']).agg({'A':'mean', 'B':'mean', "C":['mean', 'median']})

Comment: @BillyBonaros the agg function doesn't consider the NA cells right? I don't to consider the NA cells in my calculations thats why i didnt replace them with 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a division by zero in column C therefore that particular column had -inf +inf values that resulted in the empty cells in the groupby agg line of code. So thanks to the NaN cells in the groupby stage I discovered a lethal error. Thanks for your time all

Answer (score 0):

What are the `dtype` of each column? Are `A` and `B` and `C` all numeric, or can you convert them to `int` or `float`, or is your dataset dirty? If `gropuby` works for `A` and `B`, likely data quality is an issue if it suddenly fails for `C`.

As an aggregation function, you can directly call `mean()`

```
df.groupby['Sector', 'year'].mean()['C']
```

Comment: Data types are float64 for columns A, B and C

Comment: I noticed that sector and year are int64 by i dont think that its a problem for the groupby right?

Comment: Your code example works perfectly fine for me.. at least for the 3 rows you are providing. Let's narrow this down: can you run the command on your 120k rows, and only select the 'sector-year' tuple where you notice a 'strange mean value'? What is that "strange" value, what value would you expect from the few (n << 120k) rows with this exact "season-year" tuple?

Comment: As I wrote in the comments above. The calculation is wrong for sure, because before grouping by and aggregating values there are several values companies in each year for each sector for column C. So why does the grouping and aggregation cause the sector to have NaN values? even though there are companies in that year in that sector